# Finding the Number of Positions to Satisfy a Configuration

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, adhoc

You want a party complete with a laser light show.  Unfortunately, the only working laser you have found is located far away from your house and too heavy to move, so you want
to re-direct the laser light to the house using a series of mirrors.

The layout of the grid has the laser at position (0,0) pointing north (in
the positive y direction), and the house at (Hx, Hy); we can think of both
the laser and the house as points in the 2D plane.  There are already N mirrors
(1 <= N <= 100,000) scattered throughout the grids that are
aligned at angles of 45 degrees to the axes.  For example, a mirror aligned
like \ will take a beam of light entering from below and reflect it to the
left.  We can also think of the mirrors as being located at points in the
2D plane.

After setting the configuration, you notice a major flaw in the plan: the laser cannot hit the house with the mirrors in their current configuration!  As a result, you plan to run out onto the field, and hold up one more mirror (placed once again at a 45
degree angle) in order to redirect the laser onto the house. Please count
the number of locations in the field where you can stand to accomplish
this goal.

All coordinates are integers between -1,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,000. It
is guaranteed that any mirrors to be placed will be in this range as well.
The beam should never come back to (0,0) after leaving this location (and with the mirrors in their initial configuration, it is guaranteed that this will not happen). No two mirrors
occupy the same point in space, and you cannot locate herself at the 
same position as an existing mirror.

```
INPUT FORMAT:

* Line 1: The integers N, Hx, and Hy.

* Lines 2..N + 1: Line i+1 describes the ith mirror with 3 elements:
        its (x,y) location, and its orientation (either '\' or '/').

INPUT:

4 1 2
-2 1 \
2 1 /
2 2 \
-2 2 /

OUTPUT FORMAT: A single integer giving the number of locations
where you can stand to redirect the laser to the house.

OUTPUT:

2

OUTPUT DETAILS:

A mirror at (0,1) or (0,2) placed in either direction would do the trick.
```

My Attempt:
I actually attempted a brute-force solution. I first added a mirror into some random position of the field usually within a box that is 2*Hx X 2*Hy big and then simulated the mirrors. If it hit the home I would then increase my count. For small input this succeeded, but when I used bigger input the program crashed.

Comment: It looks like you copied this word-for-word from somewhere. Doing that generally doesn't get taken well on [so]. You should make it clear what exactly you want from us (code / pseudo-code / high-level approach / a hint / something else) and also show how you tried to solve the problem yourself (I usually prefer seeing a high-level description of your approach rather than code - you could even just share some failed ideas, just to prove that you tried *something*).

Comment: I actually attempted a brute-force solution. I first added a mirror into some random position of the field usually within a box that is 2*Hx X 2*Hy big and then simulated the mirrors. If it hit the home I would then increase my count. For small input this succeeded, but when I used bigger input the program crashed.

Comment: Hint: Draw the laser path with the initial configuration, and imagine another laser positioned in your house, pointing in four direction, draw all the four possible paths. Count the intersection between the laser path from the laser and from your house.